# Sending keypresses in Visual Basic console application

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to develop a Visual Basic console application to optimise a structure using Genetic Algorithms. The software I'm using occasionally throws popups to save the updated structure. I want to write a piece of code that simulates key presses (I want to press the enter key) on the active window so that I don't have manually press the enter key every 15 minutes.

I tried using

```
    SendKeys.SendWait({"ENTER"})
```

but there's no SendKeys in Console Application.

Comment: Can you be more specific?...you are throwing `MessageBox` or something like that?...if so, why are you doing that instead of writing to a log or something similar?

Comment: Project > Add Reference > pick System.Windows.Forms.  Do talk to the owner/developer of this library, hacks like this have a knack for causing more problems than solutions.  Consider for example that no user is going to stare at that console window for 15 minutes.

Comment: What is pop-up? WPF Window? Windows Forms?

Comment: Take a look at AutoIt (https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/). You can easily create a script, and then compile it into an executable that you can call from you VB code. You can capture a process handle when you launch it so that you can kill it when not needed.

Comment: @Hackerman It's like a window that appears when you try to close a program saying "Save", "Don't save" and "Cancel". By default Option Selected on that window is Save and i just want to press enter. Just in my case options are such that i can choose them only when that window finally appears.

Comment: @HansPassant I tried that. although the program compiles. it seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use my [InputHelper library](https://github.com/Visual-Vincent/InputHelper) follow these steps:

1. Download the library (not the source code) from GitHub:
   https://github.com/Visual-Vincent/InputHelper/releases

   > [image: Download the InputHelper library]
2. Extract the `.zip`-file somewhere.
3. In Visual Studio, right-click your project in the `Solution Explorer` and press `Add Reference...`.

   > [image: Project > Add Reference...]
4. Go to the `Browse` tab and locate the extracted folder from step 2, then select the `InputHelper.dll` file.

   > [image: Locate InputHelper.dll]
5. Now do step 3 again, but this time go to the `.NET` tab and import `System.Windows.Forms` (this is only needed if you are using a Console Application).

   > [image: Add a reference to System.Windows.Forms]
6. Finally, import the `InputHelperLib` namespace as well as `System.Windows.Forms` by writing this in the top of your code file:

   ```
   Imports System.Windows.Forms
   Imports InputHelperLib
   ```

Now you can use the `InputHelper.Keyboard.PressKey()` method to programmatically press a key:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports InputHelperLib

Module MainModule

    Public Sub Main()
        'Some code here...

        InputHelper.Keyboard.PressKey(Keys.Enter)

        'Some code here...
    End Sub
End Module
```

> **KEEP IN MIND** that if you are going to distribute this you must also include InputHelper's `LICENSE.txt` file with ***every copy of your application***.
>
> You may rename the file as long as the user still understands what it is for.

InputHelper currently consists of four main categories:

- **`InputHelper.Hooks`**: Classes for capturing system-wide mouse and keyboard input. This can be used to make hot keys, for instance. See the [project's wiki](https://github.com/Visual-Vincent/InputHelper/wiki) for implementation help.
- **`InputHelper.Keyboard`**: Methods for simulating physical keyboard input/key strokes.
- **`InputHelper.Mouse`**: Methods for simulating physical mouse input.
- **`InputHelper.WindowMessages`**: Methods for simulating mouse and keyboard input at a more virtual level. This utilizes window messages and can be used to target specific windows.

To explore the contents of my library right-click the namespace in your code and press `Go To Definition`.

This will open the `Object Browser`, in which you can browse the contents of my library, with all the types ("categories") on the left, and the methods/members on the right.

- **Right-click > Go To Definition**

  > [image: Go To Definition]
- **Browsing `InputHelperLib`'s contents**

  > [image: Browsing the contents of InputHelper]

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Sub keybd_event(bVk As Byte, bScan As Byte, dwFlags As UInteger, dwExtraInfo As UInteger)
End Sub
```

and simulate keypess with this

```
 keybd_event(Keys.Enter, MapVirtualKey(Keys.Enter, 0), 0, 0)
 Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
 keybd_event(Keys.Enter, MapVirtualKey(Keys.Enter, 0), &H2, 0)
```

Comment: Did you see @Hans Passant  comment? Much cleaner and easier.

Comment: if you ok with adding windows forms then why dont you just simply create a new windows form application instead of a console application?

Comment: The [**`keybd_event` function**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304(v=vs.85).aspx) is deprecated as of a couple of years ago. Please don't use it. Have a look at [**`SendInput`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx) instead, or my [**InputHelper library**](https://github.com/Visual-Vincent/InputHelper) which is kind of a wrapper for it.

Comment: @snoopcommands When i try to do that first thing that goes red is that i can not declare it as shared and Second it says that MapVirtualKey is not declared.

Comment: @VisualVincent Can you explain a bit more about how i use SendInput or InputHelper Library. Thank You.

Comment: @apoorvsrivastava : In your case I rather recommend following [Hans Passant's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50516293/sending-keypresses-in-visual-basic-console-application/50517433?noredirect=1#comment88045410_50516293), but if you are still interested in `InputHelper` here's a quick introduction: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49603724/3740093

Comment: @apoorvsrivastava : `InputHelper.Keyboard.PressKey()` would be of your interest. Visual Studio's IntelliSense will display information about it as you type (though you can also place the caret at it and press F12 for a full overview of the library).

Comment: @VisualVincent I'm sorry but i'm new to visual basics and visual studio. can you please help me by telling how to add your solution to my project it'll be really great if you could just help me out. Thank you.