# Changing IIS 6/7 Application Pool settings programmatically

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-6, application-pool

How can I programmatically change IIS application pools' settings and properties (for example: the `Enable 32-Bit Applications` setting)?

Are there reference guides on properties for IIS 6 or 7 on MSDN or Technet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/10181.aspx) on for size.

```
DirectoryEntry root = this.GetDirectoryEntry("IIS://" + this.DomainName + "/W3SVC/AppPools");
  if (root == null)
        return null;

List<ApplicationPool> Pools = new List<ApplicationPool>();
...
```

Answer (score 8):

You can solve the problem using appcmd.exe. Where "DefaultAppPool" is the name of the pool.

```
appcmd list apppool /xml "DefaultAppPool" | appcmd set apppool /in /enable32BitAppOnWin64:true
```

If you have any troubles with running it using C# take a look [How To: Execute command line in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results).

ps: Additional information about appcmd.exe you can find [here](http://blogs.iis.net/ksingla/archive/2007/06/17/things-you-can-do-by-piping-appcmd-commands.aspx). Default location of the tool is C:\windows\system32\inetsrv

Comment: Who knew you could use piping!? Thanks, this is great.

Answer (score 1):

An easier solution that worked for me

```
ServerManager server = new ServerManager();
ApplicationPoolCollection applicationPools = server.ApplicationPools;

 //this is my object where I put default settings I need, 
 //not necessary but better approach            
DefaultApplicationPoolSettings defaultSettings = new DefaultApplicationPoolSettings();

        foreach (ApplicationPool pool in applicationPools)
        {
            try
            {
                if (pool.Name == <Your pool name here>)
                {
                    pool.ManagedPipelineMode = defaultSettings.managedPipelineMode;
                    pool.ManagedRuntimeVersion = defaultSettings.managedRuntimeVersion;
                    pool.Enable32BitAppOnWin64 = defaultSettings.enable32BitApplications;
                    pool.ProcessModel.IdentityType = defaultSettings.IdentityType;
                    pool.ProcessModel.LoadUserProfile = defaultSettings.loadUserProfile;

                    //Do not forget to commit changes
                    server.CommitChanges();

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // log
            }
        }
```

and my object for example purpose

```
public class DefaultApplicationPoolSettings
{

    public DefaultApplicationPoolSettings()
    {
        managedPipelineMode = ManagedPipelineMode.Integrated;
        managedRuntimeVersion = "v4.0";
        enable32BitApplications = true;
        IdentityType = ProcessModelIdentityType.LocalSystem;
        loadUserProfile = true;

    }
    public ManagedPipelineMode managedPipelineMode { get; set; }

    public string managedRuntimeVersion { get; set; }

    public bool enable32BitApplications { get; set; }

    public ProcessModelIdentityType IdentityType { get; set;}

    public bool loadUserProfile { get; set; }
}
```