# generate EF model by System.Diagnostics.Process

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, code-generation, edmgen

after read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896270.aspx) article i tried generate EF model by System.Diagnostics.Process:

```
Process myProcess = new Process();
    var cs = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=uqs; Integrated Security=SSPI";
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\EdmGen.exe";
    myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/mode:fullgeneration /c:"+cs+" project:School /entitycontainer:SchoolEntities /namespace:SchoolModel /language:CSharp ";
    myProcess.Start();
```

but i haven't get a result, because i can't do well formed **arguments** string. As I tried, there have many quotes. how to organize argument string?

Comment: Why do you want to call EdmGen from an application at runtime?

Comment: because, in one app user can create a database with arbitrary structure, and i want to use as data model entity framework. then create other classes, and web-interface by template.

Comment: Is EF 4 an option? If so, you can use code-first, which is a better solution for this.

Comment: @Craig Stuntz: thanks. I'm using EF 4. please advise the link to information for familiarity.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2009/06/22/feature-ctp-walkthrough-code-only-for-entity-framework.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add double quotes around the connection string.

```
var cs = @"""Data Sour[...]rity=SSPI""";
```

Note the three double quotes at each end and the at.

Answer (score 1):

Point 1: I think you need at least some quotes around the connection string:

```
    myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/mode:fullgeneration \"/c:"+cs+"\" project:School ...";
```

But do examine the resulting Arguments string in the debugger to see if everything is allright.

For point 2, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results).