# cURL Proxy Identification

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, firefox, curl

I was wondering if I can use cURL in my .Net application to authenticate to a proxy and then connect with a browser without the annoying authenticate window popping up??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

cURL has many options for dealing authentication.

The command for authenticating with cURL would be:

```
 curl -u name:passwd http://machine.domain/full/path/to/file
```

as found in the [documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html).

You can learn how to use c# to execute the command and get the results with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results) question entitled "[How To: Execute command line in C#, get STD OUT results"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results).

If you really need to open the browser, you can use:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = GetDefaultBrowserPath();
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "http://user:pass@www.yahoo.com";
p.Start();
```

and the browser should open and authenticate based on the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You could also connect your application to the browser via Automation and  then send orders ( fill in input, form submit...) to handle authentification

Please also post details about authentification process of your specific proxy to help others to answer.