# Run an executable present in Windows Path using C#

Tags: c#, windows

I'm trying to run some commands, like `rails test`, using a C# command line. I tried using [How To: Execute command line in C#, get STD OUT results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results) but I'll need full path to the rails executable for that to work. Is there any alternative that will find work just like the windows command line does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can P/Invoke, you could locate the executable with [PathFindOnPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773594(VS.85).aspx). A quick google doesn't show a C# equivalent.

without P/Invoke, `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Path").Split(";")` should give you a list of paths to probe.

However, this is not the entire resolution used by ShellExecute or even the console.

Answer (score 1):

I *believe* if you have `UseShellExecute` set to true in the [`ProcessStartInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) used to start the process, it'll use the path. Haven't checked it yet - will do so when I get a chance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems to do that - but I'm unable to read the output when `UseShellExecute' is `true`. `RedirectStandardOutput' requires `UseShellExecute` set to false.

Comment: @Adam: Yes, it seems you can't have it both ways... Could you get the rails test program to dump its results to a log file which you can read?