# Reading Batch shell script output into C# .Net Program

Tags: c#, .net, windows, batch-file, cmd

For a project I am building a new front end for an old Batch script System. I have to use Windows XP and C# with .Net. I don't want to touch this old Backend system as it's crafted over the past Decade. So my Idea is to start the `cmd.exe` Program and execute the Bash script in there. For this I will use the "system" function in .Net.

But I also need to read the "Batch script commandline Output" back into my C# Program. I could redirect it into a file. But there has to be a way to get the Standard Output from `CMD.exe` in into my C# Program.

Thank you very much!

Comment: by `Bash`, do you mean `Batch`?

Comment: @Brian: I think W_P knows that.

Comment: @Dennis: Could be, but the OP did write bash and shell script several times, so I take it we're actually talking about bash. I guess a clarification is in order.

Comment: thanks all , changed maked , its windows cmd Batch, not a linux Bash script!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To: Execute command line in C#, get STD OUT results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your ways are good. But you only get the whole Output at the end. I wanted the output when the script was running. So here it is, first pretty much the same, but than  I twised the output. 
If you have problems look at:
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx

```
public void execute(string workingDirectory, string command)
{   

    // create the ProcessStartInfo using "cmd" as the program to be run, and "/c " as the parameters.
    // Incidentally, /c tells cmd that we want it to execute the command that follows, and then exit.
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(workingDirectory + "\\" + "my.bat ", command);

    procStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;

    //This means that it will be redirected to the Process.StandardOutput StreamReader.
    procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    //This means that it will be redirected to the Process.StandardError StreamReader. (same as StdOutput)
    procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

    procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    // Do not create the black window.
    procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    // Now we create a process, assign its ProcessStartInfo and start it
    System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

    //This is importend, else some Events will not fire!
     proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    // passing the Startinfo to the process
    proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;

    // The given Funktion will be raised if the Process wants to print an output to consol                    
    proc.OutputDataReceived += DoSomething;
    // Std Error
    proc.ErrorDataReceived += DoSomethingHorrible;
    // If Batch File is finished this Event will be raised
    proc.Exited += Exited;
}
```

Something is off, but whatever you get the idea...

The DoSomething is this function:

```
void DoSomething(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine);
{
   string current = outLine.Data;
}
```

Hope this Helps

Comment: `BeginOutputReadLine()` is also needed.

Comment: ^ without `proc.BeginOutputReadLine()` _(and `proc.BeginErrorReadLine()` for the error data)_, this will not work.

Answer (score 15):

Given the updated question. Here's how you can launch `cmd.exe` to run a batch file and capture the output of the script in a C# application.

```
var process = new Process();
var startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", @"/C c:\tools\hello.bat");
startinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startinfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo = startinfo;
process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine(args.Data); // do whatever processing you need to do in this handler
process.Start();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't capture the output with the `system` function, you have to go a bit deeper into the subprocess API.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
Process process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("bash", path_to_script) {
                                    UseShellExecute = false,
                                    RedirectStandardOutput = true
                                });
string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
process.WaitForExit();
if (process.ExitCode != 0) { … /*the process exited with an error code*/ }
```

You seem to be confused as to whether you're trying to run a bash script or a batch file. These are not the same thing. Bash is a unix shell, for which several Windows ports exist. “Batch file” is the name commonly given to cmd scripts. The code above assumes that you want to run a bash script. If you want to run a cmd script, change `bash` to `cmd`. If you want to run a bash script and `bash.exe` is not on your `PATH`, change `bash` to the full path to `bash.exe`.

Comment: sorry, im used to say bash but i want Windows cmd Batch skript

Comment: tank you, your code is working nicely. Two bits:  At line 7 there is an bracket to much. Second bit: after path_to_script you just leave a blanket and you can add your arguments to the script. Thank you all a lot , my boss is very happy :D