# how i can execute CMD command in c# console application?

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, sql, database

It's very simple to make a mysqldump in `cmd` on windows, simply:

*Open `cmd` and put type mysqldump uroot ppassword database > c:/data.sql*

This results in an SQL dump file for the desired database.

I'm writing a console application so I may run this command:

```
-uroot -ppass databse  > location\data.sql
```

I tried the following code to no avail:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
    new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + cmd);
```

***How might I start a `cmd` process and send my command successfully?***

Comment: You should elaborate what is the error, what happens.. maybe CMD can't be found try to put full path in there

Comment: Is it safe to add the password on the command line...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is there a reason why you don't call mysqldump directly?

```
ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = 
    new ProcessStartInfo("mysqldump", "uroot ppassword databse > c:/data.sql");
```

If there *is* a reason, your code should look like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = 
    new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", 
        "/c \"mysqldump uroot ppassword databse > c:/data.sql\"");
```

Changes:

- You where missing "mysqldump" in your `cmd` variable.
- You should put the command to be executed in the command line into quotes.

Comment: reason is simple. newbie never can do that whenever they not know everything properly. i make it to help them then they can easily do that.

Answer (score 47):

```
Process cmd = new Process();

cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

cmd.Start();

/* execute "dir" */

cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("dir");
cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
cmd.StandardInput.Close();
Console.WriteLine(cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
```

Answer (score 5):

Do you run Process.Start(psi) with the ProcessStartInfo instance you have just created?

Anyway, the following should do the work:

`string commandToExecute = @"c:\windows\system32\calc.exe";

Process.Start(@"cmd", @"/c " + commandToExecute);`

Comment: that is exactly what I am looking for, thanks friend

Answer (score 1):

[Executing Batch File in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519328/executing-batch-file-in-c)

Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

To use Powershell,

```
Process cmd = new Process();

cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe";
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

cmd.Start();

/* execute "dir" */

cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("dir");
cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
cmd.StandardInput.Close();
Console.WriteLine(cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
```

when you wish to run several commands in CMD say,

```
cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("dir && dir");
```

while in powershell, use:

```
cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("dir;dir");
```