# can i embed cmd.exe in a html document?

Tags: html

I'm building an online batch tutorial and would like to have the windows command prompt as an active element in my page. I tried using html5 embed tag.
but it says unsupported plugin. if it is possible with js or php PLEASE tell me.

Comment: You can't do that.  You could write server-side code that runs arbitrary commands, but that's a giant security hole.

Comment: a short answer is: no

Comment: The long answer is also probably no.

Comment: actually, if you want to do it for the sake of a doodling around and not having the ability to access it, you can run a windows 3.11 image in a dosbox for javascript https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsdosbox/

Comment: OK thanks. do you know what language it's written in and if html supports it. maybe I could simulate it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no, but you could emulate the functionality.

Take a look at CodeSchool, for example their Git tutorial. It is an interactive web application that responds to the commands you issue.

Comment: is there something similar that is possible?

Comment: Well... Yes but huge security hole. You can set up so that your web app runs commands but it is like inviting people to run whatever they want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565972/how-i-can-execute-cmd-command-in-c-sharp-console-application