# Change Encoding of StandardInput.WriteLine

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, ffmpeg

I am trying to run `ffmpeg` executable using the `Process` to convert an input audio file to mp3 format. Below is the example call that works very well when I do it from the `cmd.exe` in Windows:

```
"ffmpeg.dll -i "inputPath\input.wav" -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 320k -f mp3 -y "outputPath\output.mp3"
```

The input or output file paths can contain Turkish characters like `ş ö ç ğ`. So I have to take care of the encodings of `StreamWriter`.

My snippet for the `StreamWriter` is:

```
Process cmd = new Process();
cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd.Start();

Encoding tr_encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-9");

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(cmd.StandardInput.BaseStream, tr_encoding))
{
    sw.WriteLine(ffmpeg_cmd + " & exit");
}

cmd.WaitForExit();
```

But I always get `No such file or directory` error from the `ffmpeg` because the filepath contains a folder named as `şşşş` but my `StreamWriter` sends that folder name as  `■■■`.

How to send command-line arguments in different arguments?

Comment: try using utf8 strings - also try something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38533903/set-c-sharp-console-application-to-unicode-output

Comment: And why do you need to run cmd.exe at all, and write to its input? Just run ffmpeg directly.

Comment: @BugFinder Actually I couldn't run it with converting the strings in those topics either. Regarding your second answer, I was converting them with cmd.exe in windows, so I just wanted to do it in the ways in examples since I'm new to C#. Do you think it can be related to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the problem.

`iso-8859-9` was not the exact encoding type for the `ş` character. I needed to use the `ibm857` encoding for this.

Below is the fixed code snippet:

```
Process cmd = new Process();
cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd.Start();

Encoding tr_encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(857);

StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(cmd.StandardInput.BaseStream, tr_encoding);

streamWriter.WriteLine(ffmpeg_cmd + " & exit");
streamWriter.Close();
```

After this, I have been able to use Turkish characters in file paths.