# How to write unicode to Visual Studio output tab for debugging (NOT console app)?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, debugging

In my WPF app, when I attempt to use `Console.WriteLine` for debugging purposes, I get a `?` in the "Output" window when writing unicode characters.

```
Console.WriteLine("こんにちは！");
// Output: ?????!
```

The solution mentioned [in many other threads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38533904/238419) does not seem to work with WPF

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8; // Crashes
```

Is it possible to get unicode to work in the output tab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically there is no *Console* in *WPF*, however certain console commands seemingly do redirect to the *output window*. In short the *Console* is a special beast with its own set of limitation and quirks.

For debugging, use [`Debug.WriteLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline?view=netcore-3.1) to write to the *output window* instead.

```
Debug.WriteLine("こんにちは！");
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, it's weird that `Debug.WriteLine` works but `Console.WriteLine` doesn't. Thanks!

Comment: @TheGeneral,  How come the Console.WriteLine works at all without the console? wasnt the Visual Studio Hosting Process removed in vs 2017? And why does it seem to work under Framework but not under Core? Seems rather odd

Comment: @BlackLotus yeah these are interesting questions, without doing some research i really have no answers.  Maybe you could ask a question, i am sure that someone would know the answers. Or maybe ask on github why it was removed

Comment: @TheGeneral, Thank you. Thought it was worth a shot, been searching around for a while but been unable to find much information about it. Might make a post about it, would be rather intrested to know.