# How can i use special symbols from charmap in console application?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to enter a special character, but the app still displays a message «Wrong password!»
If anyone knows what my mistake is, I will be glad if you point it out. Thanks in advance.

Special character i use: ☺ (U+263A)

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a password:");

var pass = Console.ReadLine();

var key = '\u263a'.ToString();

while (pass != key)
{
    if (pass != key)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong password!");
        pass = Console.ReadLine();    
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Info: test 123");

Console.ReadKey();
```

upd.
[Screenshot 1:
variable "pass" in debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dA54g.png)

[Screenshot 2:
variable "key" in debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bagz4.png)

Comment: Probably a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38533903/set-c-sharp-console-application-to-unicode-output

Comment: Have you debugged to see what the string actually contains?

Comment: @Llama
I tried it but unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen
The string contains "\u0001" instead of "\u263a"

Comment: I am not surprised, the console is somewhat lacking in terms of handling unicode. You can get some support but I don't think it supports it fully.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen
Thanks. I solved the problem by changing the variable string to "char" and "readline" to "readkey(true)". I also removed the "key" variable and just added the desired symbol to the "if" condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put this

```
Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1200);
```

at the top of the program

Comment: Thank you! It's working! :)

Comment: No problem!! :)

Comment: You should explain what is `1200`. Why not `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode`?

Answer (score 0):

try to decode it to `UTF-8`

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a password:");

Console.InputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
var pass = Console.ReadLine();

var key = '\u263a'.ToString();

while (pass != key)
{
    if (pass != key)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong password!");
        Console.InputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        pass = Console.ReadLine();    
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Info: test 123");

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this method did not work. By the way, I noticed the variable "pass" in debug: 

After entering a character in the console, it accepts the string "\u0001" instead of "\u263a"

Comment: Probably `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode` instead.