# how to ping database from winform c#

Tags: c#, winforms, command-prompt, ping

I need to find out if my database is running, and I have to do it in a WinForm in C#.

From the command prompt (in windows 7) I run the following command:

```
dbping -c "uid=sos;pwd=cdpbszqe;eng=mydatabase;dbn=mydatabase;links=tcpip" -pd file -d > result.txt
```

The result is written (redirected) to the result.txt file
which I open and see if it was successful

How can i do the same from in C# code using WinForms?
Is it possible to ping and get a result if successful?
Do I have to ping and create a text file from the ping result, then open it in my C# App?
What's the best way to proceed?

thanks.

Comment: Are you aware of sharing your connection string (password!) with the whole world?

Answer (score 6):

No need for batch files if you just want to check if you can connect (i.e. it is running). We can test in a few line in C#.

```
private bool TestConnection()
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection("connection string")
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //log exception
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Accept as the answer if this was helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

just create a batch file with above command and run it from your windows forms application using Process class. Get some help from : 
[Executing Batch File in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519328/executing-batch-file-in-c-sharp)

Which will create your result.txt file and you can read it using any File.ReadAllLines() or whatever method you want to use.

Comment: Sounds like a lot of work for just testing a connection in C#

Comment: if it is only matter of testing connection then you should go for what @CodeBlend is saying otherwise instead of creating file you can use process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();