# Run Batch-file inside Batch-file from C#

Tags: c#, batch-file, cmd

I got two batch-files. 
The first is started through C# code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Files\\myBat.bat",  parameters + " > output.txt");
```

The second bat is started inside the first one:

```
%MY_PATH%\secondBat.bat
```

First one runs as supposed, but execution of second (inside of first bat) is ignored.
It all works until this Point.

It DOES work if started manually via cmd.exe
It ONLY does not work if started via C#.

Thanks for help

Edit: This is the Output:

```
C:\TheProg\XXXX\bin\Debug>C:\TheProg\XXXX\bin\Debug\secondBat.bat
```

It just doesn´t execute

Comment: The same effect if you run using "cmd /C"?

Comment: Check this example of how to launch a batch file - seems MUCH more verbose and may "just work" though I cannot offer any more advice than that! http://stackoverflow.com/a/5519517/1370442

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the standard-Scenario which I am not looking for. It has the exact same effect as my code.
@Artem Razin:
Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce your problem.
I created test .bat files in `C:\simplebats`

```
bat1.bat:

@echo off
echo "bat1 started"
C:\simplebats\bat2.bat

bat2.bat:

echo "bat2 started"
```

I run bat1 from visual studio the way you did:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\simplebats\\bat1.bat", " > output.txt");
```

After i run it an `output.txt` file is created in my `Debug` folder (not in `simplebats`) and it has the expected two lines:

```
"bat1 started"
"bat2 started"
```

Are you absolutely sure that the second .bat file is not fired in your situation? Maybe you can't see it being fired because the output file is created in your `Debug` folder? That is the only thing that comes to my mind..

Comment: It was something different, but your very first sentence gave me the "click"
It was actually a simple path-finding-problem.
The standard-Folder in documents is named "Visual Studio 2010" with SPACES inbetween (classic).

So just moving the folder to C:\Test was the solution. I´m a Little embarrassed now...

For some reason I can not yet post answers...

Answer (score 0):

try to start the batch file using cmd.exe and provide the path including the arguments for the batch file, as argument to `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start`

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe" , System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Files\\myBat.bat" +  parameters + " > output.txt");
```

Comment: Hello, I already tried that. It seems to ignore the argument for cmd.exe. It just opens cmd, and then cmd does nothing.

Comment: Try to add the `/k` parameter which prevents the command prompt from being closed. That might contain an error message which now will be visible

Comment: AcidJunkie, this is unneccessary because, as I said, the window DOES already stay open this way. There is no error message, just the cmd-prompt waiting for input

Comment: Okay. Has any of the statements in the batch file executed? What is the content of the first batch file?

Comment: Yes, all of them. 
It´s a bit Special: It starts a .exe two times (works), then it copies two files (works) and THEN should "just" start the second .bat
Edit: I tested what happens, if I put the .bat BEFORE the two copy-commands... it just skips it. It does not halt or abort, it simply ignores the command...

Comment: Thanks guys, I got it now...
It was actually a simple path-finding-problem.
The standard-Folder in documents is named "Visual Studio 2010" with SPACES inbetween (classic).

So just moving the folder to C:\Test was the solution. I´m a Little embarrassed now...

For some reason I can not yet post answers...

Comment: @Franky_ley glad you could find the solution