# How to pass an error message from batch file to c# or web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, batch-file

I am working on a project that controls some .cmd from a web application. Now I am stucked in a problem. I want to pass an error message from batch file to c#. That means if any error happens in .cmd, an error message will show in my web applicaton. How can I do this? I am a beginner. I really don't get any solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

look at this [Executing Batch File in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519328/executing-batch-file-in-c-sharp)

basically you absorb all the console and based on the exit code you know if there is an error and then pass that to your client

```
processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + command);
processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
// *** Redirect the output ***
processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

process = Process.Start(processInfo);
process.WaitForExit();

// *** Read the streams ***
string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

the the error can be passed to the client. The exact method by which this happens depend on your web implementation

Comment: Basically I have an error message on my batch command. When any error happens it shows it to my command prompt when I run it. 
When error happens a message "error" prompt in my command prompt. I want this "error" would come to my web application in a message box. I hope you understand the problem. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

use the **output** variable for showing the standard output and **error** variable for showing the standard error.

Thanks a lot #[Braim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/428961/braim) for your code