# Run MATLAB script from C# and return results

Tags: c#, matlab, batch-file, process

I am building a Windows Forms Application that uses a MATLAB back end. What is the best, possibly cleanest, way to do this? Furthermore, I need to grab the MATLAB output data and work with it in the Windows Forms program.

What I have done so far:

- Using the Process class I ran a batch file that calls the MATLAB
  program:

  ```
     Process process = new Process();
     process.StartInfo.FileName = @"----\run.bat";
     process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"----";
     process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
     process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
     process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
  ```

  [Executing Batch File in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519328/executing-batch-file-in-c-sharp).

I am able to run the script without a problem.  However, I cannot receive the output stream from MATLAB.  I tried all of the solutions in the link above, but it does not work in my particular situation. I assume this has something to do with MATLAB.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-function-from-c-client.html

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The best way is probably to use the COM interface supplied by Matlab.

You'll need to add a reference to your C# project referencing the Matlab Application, then instantiate an object of type MLApp, which will allow you to call Matlab. For a simple example refer to http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-function-from-a-c-client.html.