# I want to access visual studio command propmt and run a .bat file using C# code

Tags: c#

I have created .bat file for auto deployment and i want to access visual studio command propmt and run the .bat file using C# code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing Batch File in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519328/executing-batch-file-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Just add into your batch a command to execute VsDevCmd.bat first

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about deployment processes, you're in the build, and you may want to consider using MSBuild directives; just open your project file in a text editor and add an [`Exec`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx) line. I recommend using conditionals so it only executes in "release" mode, since a deployment script rarely has a place in debug builds.

To run other processes from C# code, see [`Process.Start`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx). Keep in mind this may require executing the VS Command Prompt with parameters to start your batch script.