# C#: call a batch file and skip "press any key to continue"

Tags: c#, winforms, batch-file

I'm calling a batch file in my C# program. But the batch file has that "pause" so I get the "Press any key to continue" window. I cannot edit the batch file. Is there a way to skip this? I'm using the code below([found in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519328/executing-batch-file-in-c-sharp#comment52290029_5519517)) and played around with it - but without luck.

Thank you everyone in advance.

```
int exitCode;
string command = "test.bat"
ProcessStartInfo processInfo;
Process process;
string path = @"C:\test\test";

processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + command);
processInfo.WorkingDirectory = path;
processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

process = Process.Start(processInfo);
process.WaitForExit();

string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

exitCode = process.ExitCode;

MessageBox.Show("output>>" + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(output) ? "(press any key to continue...)" : output));
MessageBox.Show("error>>" + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(error) ? "(none)" : error));
MessageBox.Show("ExitCode: " + exitCode.ToString(), "ExecuteCommand");
process.Close();
```

Comment: Some suggestions: 

1. Try using ShellExecute, 
2. Try using the switch /q with cmd

Comment: I'd personally just parse the batch file, and run each command... or there is a sendkey if you really need the dos prompt..

Comment: @Psi tried both with no luck.

Comment: @Trey Not really sure what you mean. I'm really new with C#. Anyway you can provide a code? Thanks!!!

Comment: Parsing a batch is hard if it contains conditionals or variables. Do you have a statement called `pause` in your batch file?

Comment: @Psi yes I do. But as I mentioned above, I can't change that.

Comment: Ah sry, didn't see that. So then the only thing you can do is: read the .bat, remove the `pause` in memory, save the result to a temporary location and execute that one

Comment: What I mean is a batch file is just a text file, just read in the lines, and execute them like you did cmd.  ..or just remove the pause, save to temp batch file locally, and run the damned thing.

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c \"break|" + command+"\"");
```

Comment: It doesn't complete the batch file. It exists with -1

Comment: @Besiktas - have you tried the update with the additional quotes?

Comment: My bad. Just tried it with the new quotes and now the return code is 255

Comment: @Besiktas  what happens when you execute `cmd /c "break|test.bat"` in the command prompt?

Comment: `255` generally means output to not existing pipe ,which in this case probably means that the test.bat is not found. Are sure about the execution directory?