# how to execute batch files in one by one in c#

Tags: c#

I want to execute batch files one by one so on console if I press `yes` then next file should execute if I press `no` then console is ended

```
string file = @"C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Date";
ProcessStartInfo ProcessInfo;  
foreach (string c in Directory.EnumerateFiles(file))
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = c;
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519328/executing-batch-file-in-c-sharp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing Batch File in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519328/executing-batch-file-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

You want to do like as follows and Use Windows Form

```
string file = @"C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Date";
ProcessStartInfo ProcessInfo;  
foreach (string c in Directory.EnumerateFiles(file))
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?",
                        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = c;
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a bit weak `if(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()==1)`

Comment: Please elaborate more

Comment: well, user could make a typo and select `q` instead of `1` and application would crash because of unhandled exception.

Comment: Then try with string

Comment: but, if you're reading sting from console, why don't you then check for `yes` instead of `1` which represents `yes`? You can easily write `if (Console.ReadLine().ToLower() =="yes")`, Or, you can make "Press g for yes, h for no or 89 for 'I'm not sure'"... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ConsoleKeyInfo key ;
while(true) //your loop condition
{
    key = Console.ReadKey(true);
    if(key.Key == ConsoleKey.Y)
    {
        //Do your stuff
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Hope this help