# VB.net, my code unable to run bat file

Tags: vb.net, file, batch-file, process, startup

```
Dim app As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
    If System.IO.Directory.Exists(app & "\Divers") Then
        Try
            Process.Start(app & "\Divers\b.bat")
            cs.Text = "OK"
            cs.Refresh()
        Catch ex As Exception
            eror.Text = "(B) Problems"
            cs.Text = "error"
        End Try
        Try
            Process.Start(app & "\Divers\Realtek\diver.exe")
            d.Text = "OK"
        Catch ex As Exception
            DebugLog()
            error.Text = "Driver Problems"
            cs.Text = "error"
        End Try
        Try
            Process.Start(app & "\Divers\a.bat")
            CVS.Text = "OK"
        Catch ex As Exception
            error.Text = eror.Text & "(A) Problems"
            cs.Text = "error"
        End Try
```

And that is my code guys but the bat file is not working. Is opened but do nothing, if i open the bat file manual (with a mouse and double click logic!!!) its working. Please help

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519328/executing-batch-file-in-c-sharp), and the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5519517/832052)?

Comment: Is the code going on .Start section? Is the file executed but not properly? Maybe the WorkingDirectory is not the right now it could be executing under a different folder.

Comment: You should show the contents of `ex.Message` in your app somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your batch file may be working based on a `working directory`, and because you run the batch file with software that is in a different folder, the batch file's `working directory` does not match.

Put your software in the batch file folder and try again.