# Executing a batch file from .net application fails in a certain circumstance

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file, telnet

This ticket is not a duplicate of [this popular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519328/executing-batch-file-in-c-sharp) since the solution there does not fix the problem.  Rather I think it has to do with calling a file that's residing in the `%WINDIR%\System32` directory, because calling a batch file with anything else seems to work.

I have a batch file with the the following contents:

```
telnet 10.147.36.20 11211
pause
```

I kick it off by executing the following code:

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(entry.ExecutablePath);
Process.Start(psi);
```

I get the following:

```
'telnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

even though if I execute `telnet 10.147.36.20 11211` from the command line, it works perfectly fine.

I've tried `telnet.exe`, `c:\windows\system32\telnet.exe`, `start telnet.exe` and other variations, but nothing seems to work.

What am I missing?

Comment: If you are running a batch file, the process you start should be `cmd.exe` and pass the batch file as a parameter. Can you tell us exactly what `entry.ExecutablePath` contains? Just the path to the `.bat` file?

Comment: Telnet is not installed by default on Windows since Windows Vista and Server 2008.

Comment: What does `entry.ExecutablePath` contain?

Comment: Process.Start(@"cmd", @"/c ""path_to_bat""");

Comment: @AngryHacker ensure that your bat file is in ansi encoding. For example, open in notepad, choose save as and choose Encoding: ANSI. Or at least ensure it's now not in UTF-8 with BOM, I have a suspicion that might be the reason.

Comment: Before running your batch file for the first time, you need to execute this one-time setup that installs telnet on the destination machine: `dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:TelnetClient`. After executing that command, you should be able to execute your batch file.

Comment: @RonBeyer I tried `cmd.exe /c c:\foobar\batch.bat`, per the linked question - same results.

Comment: @Squashman I installed it.  That's why when I run the same batch file from the command line, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: @torsan `entry.ExecutablePath = C:\Users\Frank.Rizzo\Desktop\Links\clear2.bat`

Comment: @pagratios I did - the results were exactly the same.  I think it has something to do with commands being in the system32 directory than anything else.

Comment: @Evk I was really hoping that was the answer, because the file was indeed in UTF-8 (without BOM).  Unfortunately converting it to ANSI did not fix the problem.

Comment: Well then I'm out of ideas. I ran your code with utf8 bat file (by accident) and it produced error like yours, but when I fixed that it ran just fine. And if you run bat (not just telnet but your bat) from command line - it runs fine?

Comment: @Icemanind It was already installed,  which is why I can run the telnet from command line

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling:

```
ProcessStartInfo(entry.ExecutablePath);
```

it looks wrong. You're passing in a path without the executable name.

Try:

```
FileInfo oFileInfo = new FileInfo(entry);
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(oFileInfo.FullName);
```

Comment: Please check [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Format this please