# Windows service that runs multiple batch commands in parallel

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, parallel-processing, windows-services

So I already know how to run two batch commands in parallel like so

```
start /b cmd /c command1 
start /b cmd /c command2
```

Now I would like to create a Windows service that does the same thing, however I don't think I can just make a service that directly runs these two commands, as stopping the service would not kill the background processes that the service created.

My service I want to make needs to run `command1` and `command2` in parallel (fire `command1` first, then `command2` while `command1` is still running) and when the service stops, both (all) of the associated processes should also stop.

I also want to avoid having to write some Python/C# program or something and do it directly from Windows/Batch/Powershell scripting if possible.

Comment: Those are not `batch commands` they're `cmd.exe` commands. Please tell us what the commands are and what they're supposed to do, _they're certainly not called `command1` and `command2`_.

Comment: @Compo hmmm I thought it wouldn't matter exactly what they were, they are both commands that "stay on" and need to be exited with ctrl-c.

if you really want me to be specific, 
`command1` is iisexpress 
`command2` is iisexpress-proxy

(with a bunch of parameters but i don't think that should matter)

Comment: You may have thought so, but you cannot just run any command as a service. If you really want a service you could consider `srvany.exe`, which although not officially supported can still work on more modern systems. You can find it in the [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657). I would suggest that you may want to investigate just running your command(s) using the Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

you can definitely do what you need from a Window Service, instead of opening a console window with the start command in .NET you can use the `Process` and `ProcessStartInfo` classes, see here:

[Executing Batch File in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5519328/559144)

in this way you can keep a reference to the `Process` object you started and on service stop you simply kill both processes.

Comment: Do I need to write a whole C# program to do it? I should have been more specific about not wanting to write an actual program (meaning, anything that isn't powershell or batch) to accomplish this. Thanks for the resource though.

Comment: A Windows service is perhaps not what you're looking for, then. Can you elaborate on what you mean by 'service'? What functionality do you require that lead you to choose Windows Service in the first place?

Comment: @veefu I want to be able to manage this "service" in a fashion similar to
`sc start MyCommands`
`sc stop MyCommands`

and services also take care of automatically restarting/stopping/etc those processes right?

Comment: @veefu I'm willing to use something else that isn't a service if I can get this same functionality

Answer (score 0):

Not 100 % sure why you want a service and what you need to do, but from your comments, the following approach might make sense.

Create Scheduled Tasks in Windows to Start, Stop, Run at system start, and run in SYSTEM (or any other) context. You an automate the creation of scheduled tasks with PowerShell.

Use PowerShell jobs for concurrent processing within PowerShell.