# Path different when running batch file from app

Tags: c#

I was getting `'jlink' is not recognized as an internal or external command` when trying to run a command from a batch file. The batch file runs fine on its own, from command prompt. I've checked the path to the application and can see it in the PATH setting.

However, I added `echo %path%` to my batch file and the application doesnt appear in the output...

How I'm launching the bat file...

```
    public bool Execute(string batchFile)
    {
        var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        processInfo.WorkingDirectory = programmersPath;
        processInfo.FileName = programmersPath + batchFile;
        processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        var process = Process.Start(processInfo);
```

My user PATH setting...

[image]

Batch file...

```
echo %path%
jlink
```

Last few lines from the path output... (i'm not pasting the whole thing but jlink is not there)

```
C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686\mingw32\bin
```

**EDIT**

I am writing a WinForms app and launching it from Visual Studio. I'm not doing anything with users/permissions. Visual studio is launched as my user, not as Admin.

when I run `echo %path%` from cmd I can segger is in there.

I'm clearly missing something, I just can't see what.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing Batch File in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519328/executing-batch-file-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Is the user running the bacth the same as your user? if it is run from (e.g) a scheduled task or a windows service, by default the user is not the current logged in user

Comment: Your Path is the Execution path ? Is this on a sheldured task or on an other user?

Comment: What is the path that your application is getting, i.e. string path = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("path"); ?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski the link you gave is regarding running a batch file. That's not my problem.

Answer (score 0):

After frantically googling every combination of how to access environment variables and forward them onto the spawned process eventually the problem went away after restarting my laptop!!! Normally, I just close it instead of shutting down.

It appears, despite installing the jlink software a fortnight ago, only a complete restart fixed this problem. I could have sworn I performed an update-and-restart more recently than that but can't be 100% sure.