# How to Run a .cmd file from C# which has multiple lines of code inside it

Tags: c#, batch-file

When I try to execute the cmd, the code inside the cmd is not getting executed. I expect that when I execute the cmd it should run the code inside that and does the operation. When I do by double-clicking the cmd file whole processes finish nicely. but through c#, the code inside the cmd file doesn't execute.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\Dump\createAndDump.cmd";
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    proc.Start();
    string outPut = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
           
    proc.WaitForExit();
    var exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
    proc.Close();
}
```

the cmd has following code to execute:
this connects to the tool and flashing of device is done.
I am doing the code as stated above but it is not able to execute the lines inside the cmd file.

```
@echo connect> flash.mtb


@for %%i in (*.s11) do (

@echo open_file "%%~fi">> flash.mtb
@echo select_all_sections>> flash.mtb
@echo add_selected_sections>>flash.mtb
)

@echo program>> flash.mtb
@echo disconnect>> flash.mtb
@echo exit>> flash.mtb

for %%j in (flash.mtb) do "C:\Program Files (x86)\xyz\Memtool 4.7\IMTtool.exe" %%~dpj%%~nxj
```

Comment: What exactly is happening and how does that differ from what you expected? What information did you get while debugging your code?

Comment: You should write your specific problem in the title. Pretend your talking with a busy colleague and you should summarize your problem in one sentence, then write the title.

Comment: When I try to execute the cmd, the code inside the cmd is not getting executed. I expect that when I execute the cmd it should run the code inside that and does the operation.
When I do by double-clicking the cmd file whole processes finish nicely. but through c#, the code inside the cmd file doesn't execute.

Comment: Add your comment to body of your question and change the title to a specific question please

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5519328/107625

Comment: It seems as if either your `C#` code should define the `WorkingDirectory`, or alternatively, your `.cmd` code should begin by defining it, (`%~dp0`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Obs.:** The string in the path/code **`\xyz\`**, can be edited to **`\RealNameFolder\`**. Would it be necessary?

Considering:

1. Yours `*.s11` files are in the **`Dump`** folder:

```batch-file
 D:
  |
  \---Dump
          0001.s11
          0005.s11
          0010.s11
          0015.s11
```

2. The folder for creating the **`flash.mtb`** file is **`\Dump`**

```batch-file
 D:
  |
  \---Dump
          0001.s11
          0005.s11
          0010.s11
          0015.s11
          flash.mtb
```

3. The **`createAndDump.cmd`** file is one level before the `\Dump` folder:

```batch-file
 D:
  |
  |   createAndDump.cmd 
  |
  \---Dump
```

4. The **`C#`** executable and **`createAndDump.cmd`** are in the same folder:

```batch-file
 D:
  |   createAndDump.cmd 
  |   RunBat.exe
  |
  \---Dump
```

5. Use **[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)** code suggested below to get the work directory where the executable is running, and use this to try call the bat:

```batch-file
string pathdir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
             var process = new Process();
             var startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Path.Combine(pathdir, "createAndDump.cmd"));
```

6. Can you please try to use the suggested **[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)** code, to also signal you (producing a **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)** output), where it is easier to check what you have wrong, whether in your **[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)**, or in the execution of your **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)**?

```batch-file
process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, argsx) => Console.WriteLine(argsx.Data);
```

---

- **[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)** code:

```batch-file
 using System;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Diagnostics;
 
 namespace ConsoleApplication
 {
     class Program
     {
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
 
             string pathdir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
             var process = new Process();
             var startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Path.Combine(pathdir, "createAndDump.cmd"));
             startinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
             startinfo.UseShellExecute = false;

             process.StartInfo = startinfo;
             process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, argsx) => Console.WriteLine(argsx.Data);
             process.Start();
             process.BeginOutputReadLine();
             process.WaitForExit();
         }
     }
 }
```

**[cmd#](/questions/tagged/cmd%23)** code:

You can try using **`cd /d "%~dp0"`**, also use default `Program files` (**`ProgramFiles`**, **`ProgramFiles(x86)`**, **`%ProgramW6432%`**) folders, to try find and get the full path to your **`\Memtool.exe`** file:

```batch-file
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

cd /d "%~dp0" && pushd .\Dump && >"%~dp0Dump\flash.mtb" (
     echo\connect && for %%i in (*.s11)do echo\open_file "%%~fi" && echo\select_all_sections && echo\add_selected_sections
     echo\program && echo\disconnect && echo\exit ) || echo. Yes, something is very wrong here... && endlocal && goto :EOF
     
popd && (for %%i in (ProgramFiles,ProgramFiles(x86^),ProgramW6432)do if /i defined %%~i 2>nul (for /f tokens^=^* %%M in ('
     %__APPDIR__%where.exe /r "!%%~i!\xyz\Memtool 4.7" "IMTtool.exe"')do echo/%%M|%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /ei xe>nul && (
     pushd "!%%~i!\xyz\Memtool 4.7" && "!%%~i!\xyz\Memtool 4.7\%%~nxM" "%~dp0Dump\flash.mtb" && endlocal && goto :EOF )))
```

Comment: @AutoEng Is the bat called in the same folder where you have the `*.s11` files?

Comment: This is also what I found as an issue. As my project is huge and carry the legacy, the compiler was searching for s11 file on one specific folder while doing debug, I thought it to be in debug folder inside the bin of solution(default), but code for finding the file was done by some developer long back and was hardcoded(don' know why :P). This was only the issue and both the shell scripts yours and mine worked after placing the files in folder.  Thanks. :)     Nice to see you got the question and also answered to the point else I am only getting -1 to my question and no answers. lol :D

Comment: @AutoEng 
For help proposal, 1st point of understanding or problem, here are people who would easily help you, but some difficulty in understanding the problem resulted in downs votes