# How to read message from batch file from C# application

Tags: c#, batch-file, robocopy

I have a batch file that copy file from one folder to another folder. So I would like to run this file from a C# windows services then I would like to read if the script generate an error or it works correctly. 
This is my code for lunch it but I don't Know how to read the message of the script:

SCRIPT CODE:

```
REM
REM This script moves files with results from GOLD server and saves them on MES06 server on .
REM IMPORT folder.
REM
REM Robocopy Options:
REM /R:2     Two retries on failed copies (default is 1 million)
REM /W:5     Wait 5 seconds between retries (default is 30 sec).
REM
REM GOLD QAS Inbound Folder: \\goldqas01.app.pmi\limscihome$\RootDirectory
REM 


for /f "delims=: tokens=2,3" %%j in (F:\MES2GOLD\copy_list_test.txt) do ROBOCOPY.EXE %%j %%j\..\BACKUP *.* /R:2 /W:5 /log+:%%j\..\LOGS\MES2GOLD.log & ROBOCOPY.EXE %%j %%k *.* /R:2 /W:5 /MOV /log+:%%j\..\LOGS\MES2GOLD.log

PAUSE
```

C# Code:

```
    public void execute(string workingDirectory, string command)
    {

        // create the ProcessStartInfo using "cmd" as the program to be run, and "/c " as the parameters.
        // Incidentally, /c tells cmd that we want it to execute the command that follows, and then exit.

        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", @"/c C:\Users\mcastrio\Desktop\GOLD2MES.bat");

        procStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;

        //This means that it will be redirected to the Process.StandardOutput StreamReader.
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        //This means that it will be redirected to the Process.StandardError StreamReader. (same as StdOutput)
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        // Do not create the black window.
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        // Now we create a process, assign its ProcessStartInfo and start it
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

        //This is importend, else some Events will not fire!
        proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        // passing the Startinfo to the process
        proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;

        // The given Funktion will be raised if the Process wants to print an output to consol                    
        proc.OutputDataReceived += DoSomething;
        // Std Error
        proc.ErrorDataReceived += DoSomethingHorrible;
        // If Batch File is finished this Event will be raised
        proc.Exited += Exited;
    }
```

Can we help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742087/reading-batch-shell-script-output-into-c-sharp-net-programm

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519328/executing-batch-file-in-c-sharp try this too

Comment: Definitely a duplicate question!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below inside your loop:

```
var startInfo = p.StartInfo;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ibm850");
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.FileName = filebatch;
startInfo.Arguments = arguments;

p.Start();
var output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Or just use [ProcessHelper.Run](https://github.com/giacomelli/TestSharp/blob/master/TestSharp/ProcessHelper.cs#L26) from [TestSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TestSharp/) library:

```
ProcessHelper.Run(string exePath, string arguments = "", bool waitForExit = true)
```

Comment: But what is p.StartInfo?

Comment: Excuse me but I don't have fixed my problem. I have see another post, that we have linked at this post, but not Found. I have just modify my post.