# Redirect batch script output to visual studio text area

Tags: .net, batch-file, visual-studio-2013, cmd

I have a batch script which I have packaged into a visual studio solution (.NET). When i click a button in my project, I want to be able to execute this script but redirect the output from the cmd window to a text area inside the visual studio solution. Is this possible?

At the moment this is going to be a one way process where info is displayed from the cmd output to visual studio, however later down the line I am looking to be able to pass parameters to this script as it is developed but from the form interface and not straight into the cmd window.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

Cheers,

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542599/having-the-output-of-a-console-application-in-visual-studio-instead-of-the-conso

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading Batch shell script output into C# .Net Programm,](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742087/reading-batch-shell-script-output-into-c-sharp-net-programm)