# How to run a Command in C# and retrieve data from it?

Tags: c#, cmd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How To: Execute command line in C#, get STD OUT results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results)

Hello,

In my C# application, I want to run a Command from command promt and want its output and maipulate its output. If required, want to close the process and display error or appropriate message. To stop the process, I have to press "F4' key on command prompt. Till the process is stopeed or killed, it has to be alive only.

How is that possible. Any help is highly appreciated. I am stuck with this and would be glad if any body helps me solve my problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Do you need something like this

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                CreateNoWindow = false,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                FileName = @"program",
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
                Arguments = "agruments"
            };

            using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
            {
                if (exeProcess != null) exeProcess.WaitForExit();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx

But I don't think we can stop execution of the command by putting F4 on command line.

Comment: Thanks, I got the part of creating object of Process. I am basically trynig to connect to a server and the server gives output till it is not disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using `Process` under `System.Diagnostics` to launch and get the outputs
Can you please elaborate on what type of commands and the intent of it, not clear on that part

Comment: As this thread is marked as "CLOSED" I don't think I will be able to shaer more with you on this thread. But I need more than this. Kindly refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884175/manipulate-the-output-receiving-from-command-run-and-act-accordingly-c   to know more avout my problem. its not just like execute a "dir" ike command, retrieve output and the process is already "Exited". It way more than that. I need your guidance, please help me to your best.  - Thanks