# how to run program with command?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, windows-ce

i need to run program with command in Windows-CE or Windows-Mobile

for example:  `RunMe.exe true`    or   `RunMe.exe false`

if the program returns true the program will do something and if the program returns false

the program will do something else.

how can I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear.

If you want to *write* such a program, use the `string[] args` parameter to `Main()`.
(Or call `Environment.GetCommandLineArguments()`)

If you want to *run* such a program, call `Process.Start`.

Answer (score 0):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results) (which got it from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx)):

```
// Start the child process.
Process p = new Process();
// Redirect the output stream of the child process.
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "YOURBATCHFILE.bat";
p.Start();
// Do not wait for the child process to exit before
// reading to the end of its redirected stream.
// p.WaitForExit();
// Read the output stream first and then wait.
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this without writing another program, you can create a shortcut file to launch your application with the desired command-line options.

The format of a shortcut file looks like this:

`[number of ASCII characters after pound sign allocated to command-line arguments]#[command line] [optional parameters]`

For example:

`40#\Windows\MyApp.exe parameter1 parameter2`

see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms861519.aspx