# How to execute multiple commands in a single line

Tags: windows, cmd

I know Unix has the following command which can execute multiple commands in a single line, how can I do this in DOS?

```
command1 ; command2 ; command3 ...
```

Comment: You can chain commands by using an ampersand `&`, e.g. echo Hello & echo World

Comment: Or you could get [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), and have unix cmds on windows :-)

Comment: In actual DOS or the Windows command-prompt?

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Googling gives me this:

---

**`Command A & Command B`**

Execute *Command A*, then execute *Command B* (no evaluation of anything)

---

**`Command A | Command B`**

Execute *Command A*, and redirect all its output into the input of *Command B*

---

**`Command A && Command B`**

Execute *Command A*, evaluate the errorlevel after running and if the exit code (errorlevel) is 0, only then execute *Command B*

---

**`Command A || Command B`**

Execute *Command A*, evaluate the exit code of this command and if it's anything but 0, only then execute *Command B*

---

Comment: Now, in 2014, googling gives me this.

Comment: Google doesn't answer questions, Google finds people's answers to questions.  If no one answers the question first, Googling is pointless!  :-)

Comment: I just found this googling and it helped me :)

Comment: If I define some aliases (e.g.
doskey a=echo a
doskey b=echo b)
I can't run a && b. Is there a way around it?

Comment: @Yaniv Ask this as a new question (clicking the "Ask Question" button on the top right), not as a comment.

Comment: You know honestly the way the stackoverflow community punishes unpopular questions and jumps on people who asks duplicate questions makes asking a question in a comment make a lot more sense.  Granted, people should look in stackoverflow first before asking a question, but some people suck at searching and sometimes searches bring newer questions up first (like this one).  I guess that's a problem with google.

Comment: For posterity: `errorlevel` (aka `Exist status`) and `exit code` are synonymous. They refer to the value returned by a child process to a parent process (e.g., the OS shell and the program called from the shell). The former are terms used with DOS-OS's and the latter is associated with Unix systems.  See [Wiki: Exit Status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status)