# Error codes seemingly ignored by '&&' on Windows command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have some Batch scripts I use for automating application build processes, most of which involve chaining commands together using the `&&` operator. Admittedly, I'm more experienced with Linux, but based on that experience `some_command && other_command` should result in `other_command` being run **iff `some_command` returns an exit code of 0**. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13719223) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8055430) seem to agree with that. However this appears not to be the case on Windows cmd.exe, all of the scripts run regardless of the error code of the previous.

I decided to make a simple test for this to convince myself I wasn't going insane. Consider this `test.bat`, which returns an exit code of 1:

```
@echo off
EXIT /B 1
```

Running `test.bat && echo This shouldn't print` prints 'This shouldn't print'. But since the exit code is clearly 1, `echo` should *not* be called. I've tested that the error code was actually 1 using the `%errorlevel%` variable, they're coming out as expected (0 before I run the script, 1 after).

On Linux I tried the same thing. Here's `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
exit 1
```

Running `./test.sh && echo "This shouldn't print"` gives no output, exactly what I expected.

What's going on here?

(**Note:** OS is Windows 7 Enterprise)

Comment: Pls provide a REAL example of the script, where you face this problem. Otherwise, how do you expect anyone to help you  - by guessing together?

Comment: Did you test that without using the /B switch?

Comment: You are talking about variable `%errorCODE%`, but you mean `%errorLEVEL%`, right??

Comment: @sambul35 I tried to give a minimal but sufficient example to showcase the issue, no point in bloating the question with details that are irrelevant to it.

Comment: @Squashman Running without the /B switch causes cmd to exit, so I couldn't observe the output

Comment: @aschipfl Yes I meant %errorlevel%, thanks for pointing that out. Will edit

Comment: @SilverSylvester You draw wrong generalized assumption from a rather atypical && use example. The result depends on what command sequence you use.

Comment: Great question and nice minimal reproducible example. I really don't understand the criticism here. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `call` to run the batch script, like this:

```
call test.bat && echo This shouldn't print
```

Without `call`, the `&&` operator does not receive the `ErrorLevel` returned by the batch script.

---

When you run a batch file from within another one, you need to use `call` in order to return to the calling batch file; without `call`, execution terminates as soon as the called batch file has finished...:

```
call test.bat
echo This is going to be displayed.
```

...but:

```
test.bat
echo You will never see this!
```

When running `test.bat` is involved in a command line where multiple commands are combined (using the concatenation operator `&`, the conditional ones `&&` and `||`, or even a block of code within parentheses `()`), all the commands following `test.bat` are ecexuted even if `call` was not used. This is because the entire command line/block has already been parsed by the command interpreter.

However, when `call` is used, the `ErrorLevel` value returned by the batch file is received (which is `1` in our situation) and the following commands behave accordingly:

```
call test.bat & echo This is always printed.
echo And this is also always printed.

call test.bat && echo This is not printed.

call test.bat || echo But this is printed.

(
    call test.bat
    echo This is printed too.
    echo And again this also.
)

call test.bat & if ErrorLevel 1 echo This is printed.
```

But without `call` you will get this...:

```
test.bat & echo This is printed.
echo But this is not!
```

...and...:

```
test.bat && echo Even this is printed!
echo Neither is this!
```

...and...:

```
test.bat || echo But this is not printed!
echo And this is not either!
```

...and:

```
(
    call test.bat
    echo This is printed.
    echo And this as well.
)
```

It seems that the `&&` and `||` operators receive an `ErrorLevel` of `0` -- even in case `ErrorLevel` has already been set before `test.bat` is executed, strangely. Also when `if ErrorLevel` is used, the behaviour is similar:

```
test.bat & if ErrorLevel 1 echo This is not printed!
```

...and...:

```
set = & rem This constitutes a syntax error.
test.bat & if ErrorLevel 1 echo This is still not printed!
```

Note that the commands behind `test.bat` execute *after* the batch script, even without `call`.

Comment: There are more details involved here. In `test.bat && echo This...` line, the `test.bat` file is _not_ invoked via `call`; this means that that Batch file _never_ returns, so there is not really any `ErrorLevel` **_returned_**. The commands placed after the `&&` or `&` are executed just because the whole line was already parsed, but any line placed below this one is never executed (because the execution ends at `test.bat` file).   The `call` command just make that after the `test.bat` file ends, the execution returns to this line, so the `&&` can make its job...

Comment: Yes, @Aacini, I extended my answer accordingly; thank you!