# Run two command line instructions from matlab

Tags: r, matlab, cmd

I want to run a R script from matlab.

I can run the R code perfectly from cmd using:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.3\bin\x64"
R CMD BATCH "C:\Users\name\Desktop\Code.R"
```

However in Matlab I am not sure how to run this two instructions. 
First, I noticed that I could use:

```
system('cd "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.3\bin\x64"')
```

to run a commnand line command. However I need to run two. And making:

```
system('cd "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.3\bin\x64"')
system('R CMD BATCH "C:\Users\name\Desktop\Code.R"')
```

does not work.

I also saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719174/how-to-execute-multiple-commands-in-a-single-line) about running multiple command line instructions in a single line, but also that did not work.

Anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: Create a batch file that runs the instructions and call that

Comment: I would like to avoid that, and I want the code to be transparent as possible. So calling a batch that calls an R script...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script should generally not care where it’s executed. So you don’t need the `cd` statement at all:

```
system('"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.3\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD BATCH "C:\Users\name\Desktop\Code.R"')
```

Be careful thought that the R path might not always be the same … it’s probably safer to find R’s location programmatically. Though how to do that in Matlab on Windows, I don’t know.

Furthermore, I honestly don’t really know why `R CMD BATCH` even exists but I strongly recommend using `RScript` instead. [It works much nicer for a number of reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3415135/1968).

The code then becomes:

```
system('"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.3\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" "C:\Users\name\Desktop\Code.R"')
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you!

Answer (score -3):

Try to use `dos` command instead of `system`.

Comment: There is no difference between `dos` and `system` on Windows platforms.