# How do I run two commands in Windows CMD?

Tags: windows, bash, cmd, terminal

I have two commands in that I need to run on CMD.I want to make a bash file so that I can run commands in one click.And I want to wait some time for executing 1st one completely

```
sudo docker run -d --link selenium-hub:hub selenium/node-chrome
sudo docker run -d --link selenium-hub:hub selenium/node-firefox
```

Comment: What is sudo here? Is that a Windows sudo.exe, or are you running the Windows 10 Linux subsystem? Are these commands running in a WSL bash script? What does this have to do with the CMD shell?

Comment: I am trying to install docker on my windows pc and in documentation  they mention this cmd for windows and i want to run it by one click

Comment: Is this Windows-related? If not, please remove the tag [tag:cmd]!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with "&&"

you could put this in a "script.bat":

```
sudo docker run -d --link selenium-hub:hub selenium/node-chrome && sudo docker run -d --link selenium-hub:hub selenium/node-firefox
```

And if you want to wait between the commands, use something like this:

```
sudo docker run -d --link selenium-hub:hub selenium/node-chrome && sleep 1000 && sudo docker run -d --link selenium-hub:hub selenium/node-firefox
```

You can chain this indefinetely. For example you could do `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt autoremove`

As stated in another answer, `&&` this will check if the previous command was successful. If you don't want any validation you have to use `;` for BASH or `&` for CMD

Answer (score 0):

create a file with .sh and put the content as :

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo docker run -d --link selenium-hub:hub selenium/node-chrome 
sudo docker run -d --link selenium-hub:hub selenium/node-firefox
```

In windows just Logical AND will work:

```
sudo docker run -d --link selenium-hub:hub selenium/node-chrome && sudo docker run -d --link selenium-hub:hub selenium/node-firefox
```

Refer this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719174/how-to-execute-multiple-commands-in-a-single-line):

```
Command A && Command B
```

Execute Command A, evaluate the errorlevel after running and if the exit code (errorlevel) is 0, only then execute Command B

```
Command A & Command B
```

Execute Command A, then execute Command B (no evaluation of anything)

Comment: Don't forget to `dos2unix` your shell script as BASH is not able to handle windows EOL pattern.

Comment: You need to enable bash from the windows features in order to have Bash shell enabled. Its a feature in windows 10. Or else you use cmd prompt and use the second approach.

Comment: Yes it is. Or use an external shell like http://cmder.net, or gnu utilities. Hopefully, bash exists since much more than microsoft decided to add it to windows… !
I presume the author of the question already has a bash installed, since he has a sudo, and various shell commands in his script :)