# How to find the port at which the particular service is listening programatically

Tags: c#, tcp, windows-services

I know the service name. Is there any option to find the port number at which service is listening?

PS:

`netstat -a -n -o` will give IP, PORT, PID

while

```
tasklist /SVC /FI "SERVICES eq ServiceName" will give, Imagename, PID
```

How to merge the results of both to get the port of that particular service.

Comment: Belongs on [superuser](http://superuser.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way to go:

1. use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367557/how-to-parse-command-line-output-from-c) to get the output of a cmd command
2. use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) to split each line into substrings
3. compare the substring with the service name you want, if it is the same. Get the PID of the service.
4. Execute second command. Parse it, get the portNumber

Remark: It is wise to compare string always in the same casing, so either uppercase or lowercase all strings before comparing

Good luck