# how can I get list of active LAN user using ARP

Tags: c#, network-programming, lan, arp

in command prompt we can get list of ACTIVE user's IP [on LAN] using command like

```
arp - g
```

How can I get similar list using C#

Comment: Why don't you run that command as you normally would, and look at the result from your program?

Comment: how to run a command prompt code from c# app?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367557/how-to-parse-command-line-output-from-c)

Comment: @mebjas: you can use `Process` class to execute `commands` from c# program , see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Process` to execute commands from `c# program`

Try This:

```
        Process process = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = "arp";
        startInfo.Arguments = "-g";
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;

        process.Start();
        String strData = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```