# How to display all ip and mac address in same wifi connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, networking, arp

**Display all ip and mac address in same wifi connection**

As I have tried to use cmd and enter 
"`arp -a`" 
to show all ip and MAC address.

I would like to do something like this on ASP.NET MVC C# to show all IP and MAC address on web
Is it possible?
If yes how to do it for easily
thank you :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can I get list of active LAN user using ARP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20707604/how-can-i-get-list-of-active-lan-user-using-arp)

Comment: Do you want to show all addresses on the same network as the *client* (i.e. browser) or the *server*?

Answer (score -2):

To show the IP address in C# :

```
    string strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
    string clientIPAddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(strHostName).GetValue(1).ToString();

    TextBox1.Text = clientIPAddress;
```

After you got your IP address , the below link should help you to get the MAC address

[How do I obtain the physical (MAC) address of an IP address using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187894/how-do-i-obtain-the-physical-mac-address-of-an-ip-address-using-c)

Comment: I already got my IP and MAC address. but what I want is to get IP and MAC address form the other client in the same wifi.  but thank far answer anyways :)

Answer (score -2):

Use the System.Diagnostics functionality to execute the arp -a command and parse through the results.

There is a blog that addresses how to do this here: http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/11/08/Resolve_IP_Address_And_Host_Name_From_MAC_Address_using_CSharp_and_Windows_ARP_Utility