# Programmatically install Apk files from C# application

Tags: c#, .net, installation, apk

I need to write a program where i can select an apk files which will be installed in the connected devices(via USB) I can see many threads referring on how to install exe and msi but no useful links for installing apk from C#. Can anyone provide a clue to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

With usb debugging enabled in the android device and android sdk and proper drivers on the computer you could use the adb command-line tool (sdk-path/platform-tools/adb.exe):

```
adb install pathToYourApk.apk
```

There are multiple answers regarding how to run a command-line tool with c#, for example: 
[How to parse command line output from c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367557/how-to-parse-command-line-output-from-c/5367686#5367686)