# C# execute external program and capture (stream) the output

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I'm making a program to work with some video files.

I'm using the ffmpeg executable to merge several files in a single file.
This command takes several minutes to finish, so, I need a way to "monitor" the output, and show a progress bar on GUI.

Looking at the following stackoverflow topics:

- [How to parse command line output from c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367557/how-to-pcarse-command-line-output-from-c/5367686#5367686)
- [Process.start: how to get the output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291912/process-start-how-to-get-the-output)
- [How To: Execute command line in C#, get STD OUT results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results)

I made this code:

```
Process ffmpeg = new Process
{
  StartInfo = 
  {
    FileName = @"d:\tmp\ffmpeg.exe",
    Arguments = "-f concat -safe 0 -i __sync.txt -c copy output.mp4",
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    WorkingDirectory = @"d:\tmp"
  }
}

ffmpeg.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
ffmpeg.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => Debug.WriteLine(e.Data);
ffmpeg.ErrorDataReceived += (s, e) => Debug.WriteLine($@"Error: {e.Data}");
ffmpeg.Start();
ffmpeg.BeginOutputReadLine();
ffmpeg.WaitForExit();
```

When I run this code, the ffmpeg start to merge files, I can see the ffmpeg process on Windows Task Manager, and if I wait long enough, the ffmpeg finish the job without any error. But, the `Debug.WriteLine(e.Data)` is never called (no output on Debug window). Tried to change to `Console.WriteLine` too (again, no output).

So, after this, I tried this another version:

```
Process ffmpeg = new Process
{
  StartInfo = 
  {
    FileName = @"d:\tmp\ffmpeg.exe",
    Arguments = "-f concat -safe 0 -i __sync.txt -c copy output.mp4",
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    WorkingDirectory = @"d:\tmp"
  }
}

ffmpeg.Start();
while (!ffmpeg.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
{
  var line = ffmpeg.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(line);
  Console.WriteLine(line);
}
ffmpeg.WaitForExit();
```

Again, the ffmpeg is started without any error, but the C# "hangs" on `While (!ffmpeg.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)` until ffmpeg is finished.

If I execute the exact command on Windows prompt, a lot of output text is showed with progress of ffmpeg.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the problem.

For some reason, ffmpeg output the progress on stderr, not stdout.

So, on first version, after the `ffmpeg.BeginOutputReadLine();`, I included the following line:
`ffmpeg.BeginErrorReadLine();`.

Now, I can monitor the progress using the stderr of ffmpeg.

Final code:

```
Process ffmpeg = new Process
{
    StartInfo = {
        FileName = @"d:\tmp\videos\ffmpeg.exe",
        Arguments = "-f concat -safe 0 -i __sync.txt -c copy output.mp4",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        WorkingDirectory = @"d:\tmp\videos\gopro"
    }
};

ffmpeg.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
ffmpeg.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => Debug.WriteLine(e.Data);
ffmpeg.ErrorDataReceived += (s, e) => Debug.WriteLine($@"Error: {e.Data}");
ffmpeg.Start();
ffmpeg.BeginOutputReadLine();
ffmpeg.BeginErrorReadLine();
ffmpeg.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Is this block still correct with the current ffmpeg version?
I tried your code above and ffmpeg still report progress through error data.

Answer (score 5):

I have found this post few weeks ago when I was looking for answer for my problem.
I tried to start ffmpeg process and pass arguments to it but it take sooo long to do everything. At this point I use [Xabe.FFmpeg](https://github.com/tomaszzmuda/Xabe.FFmpeg) as it doing this out of the box and don't have to worry about ffmpeg executables because have feature to download latest version.

```
bool conversionResult = await new Conversion().SetInput(Resources.MkvWithAudio)
  .AddParameter(String.Format("-f image2pipe -i pipe:.bmp -maxrate {0}k -r {1} -an -y {2}",bitrate, fps, outputfilename))
  .Start();
```

There is documentation available [here](https://xabe.net/product/xabe_ffmpeg/) that shows how to get current percent of conversion. At this moment I thing showing output for concatenating videos doesn't work but they are working on it.