# Input & Output from cmd.exe shell

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, command-line

I am trying to create a Windows Forms C# project that interacts with the command prompt shell (cmd.exe).

I want to open a command prompt, send a command (like ipconfig) and then read the results back into the windows form into a string, textbox, or whatever.

Here is what I have so far, but I am stuck. I cannot write or read to the command prompt.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());

            System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/k dir *.*";
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            p.Start();

            StreamWriter inputWriter = p.StandardInput;
            StreamReader outputWriter = p.StandardOutput;
            StreamReader errorReader = p.StandardError;
            p.WaitForExit();

        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to run cmd.exe?  Assuming ipconfig is a standalone executable, you should be able to run it directly.

Comment: ipconfig might just be an example/prof of concept.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a SO question that will give you the information you need:

[How To: Execute command line in C#, get STD OUT results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results)

Basically, you ReadToEnd on your System.IO.StreamReader.

So, for example, in your code you would modify the line `StreamReader errorReader = p.StandardError;` to read

```
using(StreamReader errorReader = p.StandardError)
{
   error = myError.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var yourcommand = "<put your command here>";

  var procStart = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + yourcommand);
  procStart.CreateNoWindow = true;
  procStart.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
   procStart.UseShellExecute = false;

   var proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
   proc.StartInfo = procStart;
   proc.Start();
   var result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

   Console.WriteLine(result);
```