# Trouble executing a C++ console application from a C# GUI

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am trying to execute a console application developed in C++, although in C# when I use a method such as:

```
private void StartProcess()
{
Process.Start("consoleapp.exe");
}
```

It does not appear or even seem to execute, no exceptions thrown etc.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If there's no exception then the process was launched. Are you sure `consoleapp.exe` isn't just immediately closing for some reason?

Comment: @Sven That's exactly what I thought at first, but when run normally e.g. by double clicking on the executable file it opens up a window fine

Comment: Maybe you could use a tool like sysinternals Process Monitor to figure out what's going on. I also suggest taking a look at the `Process` instance returned by the `Process.Start` method. Pay attention to properties such as `HasExited` and `ExitCode`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, try doing it like this,

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class ProcessStart{
    static void Main(string[] args){

        Process sample = new Process();

        sample.StartInfo.FileName   = "sample.exe";
        sample.Start();
    }
}
```

the key code is in the main function, just make sure the exe is in the same directory, and include the

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

at the top.

this code works for me and seems the most correct way.
hope i helped.

```
    Process sample = new Process();

    sample.StartInfo.FileName   = "sample.exe";
    sample.Start();
```

just change the Process sample to w/e you want, so sample can be w/e you want.

you may also pass arguments to the exe using this.

```
sample.StartInfo.Arguments = "sample argument";
```

just put this before the starting the exe part.

hope i helped :)

Comment: Your code is identical in function to the OP's code, just more verbose. It will not solve his problem.

Comment: you sure? I just thought this was  different, he also doesn't seem to be declaring a new process. Therefore, i offered mine. however thanks for telling me.

Comment: The static `Process.Start` methods return a new instance. It's just a shorthand way of doing what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Is consoleapp.exe in the same directory as your c# executable or in the path?

There is a good description of how to do this in the following article:

[How To: Execute command line in C#, get STD OUT results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results)

Comment: It's in the same directory as the executable

Comment: Well, it could be an issue of directing standard output.  I would have thought that by default it would pop up a window like double-clicking the file in explorer, but I would follow the example where it redirects stdout and then reads the stream.