# Running git update on massive directory from c# windows form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, git, cygwin

I am building a tool that will iterate though files to find function names. The problem being is that the location of the tool and the files are not tied together so a git command needs to be run to download all repositories and update them to HEAD. How do you setup and then run GIT commands with C# windows forms. Give me as much detail as possible as this is all new territory for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another question on using the command line from within c#.  The answer should be what you are looking for.
[how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results)

Comment: looking into it now thanks ill get back to you, hopefully this works with tortoise git and the git bash