# Is there any cmd callback?

Tags: c#

Obviously I can execute something with cmd console using `Process.Start();`

Is there any way to get output of that process? For example, I could have something like...

```
Process.Start("sample.bat");
```

... in my C# winforms application and sample.bat will contain something like:

```
echo sample loaded
```

First Question: is there any way to retrieve that `sample loaded`, after bat execution?
Second question: is there a way to use it without popped up console window?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx

Comment: And see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459397/how-to-easily-run-shell-commands-using-c

Comment: only ask one question in each post

Comment: possible duplicate of [Process.start: how to get the output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291912/process-start-how-to-get-the-output)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an example of exactly how to do this in the [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx) documentation:

```
// Start the child process.
Process p = new Process();
// Redirect the output stream of the child process.
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "Write500Lines.exe";
p.Start();
// Do not wait for the child process to exit before
// reading to the end of its redirected stream.
// p.WaitForExit();
// Read the output stream first and then wait.
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use

`Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo)`

There are a few ways to hook into I/O including `ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput` available.  You can use these overloads to read output from your batch files.  You can also hook into the `Exited` event to know when execution is complete.

Use `CreateNoWindow` for no window.

Answer (score 0):

Set `process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput` to true and subscribe to `process.OutputDataReceived`

```
using (var process = new Process())
{
    process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("exename");
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    process.OutputDataReceived += (s, ev) =>
    {
        string output = ev.Data;
    };


    process.Start();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```