# handling an executable file in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#

My env is Visual Studio 2008 C# and .Net. I like to call an executable from the code and pass parameters to it and then get the output. How do I do this?

Thanks
Bruce

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To: Execute command line in C#, get STD OUT results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
processInfo.FileName =FileName.exe;
processInfo.WorkingDirectory = fileDirectory;
processInfo.RedirectStandardInput =false;
processInfo.CreateNoWindow =true;
processInfo.UseShellExecute =false;
Process startRestore = Process.Start(processInfo);
startRestore.WaitForExit();
```

Replace your file with "FileName.exe" and File path with fileDirectory.
I hope it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) to start a process. How you give it data and get the output will depend on the executable, but you can pass command line arguments, and if it writes its output to a file, that will be simple. You can capture its standard output, standard error and standard input streams too - ideally use [`ProcessStartInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) to configure everything you need before starting the process.

Reading/writng  data from the process via the standard output/error/input *can* be slightly tricky (as you may need to use multiple threads) so if you *can* specify command line arguments to specify input and output files, that would be ideal.

Comment: Further to @Jon's answer this link provides a number of useful tutorials: http://www.dotnetperls.com/process-start