# How to call a Java programme from .Net?

Tags: java, .net, cross-language

I have a little java programme, that responsible for sending message via mobile phone, and which is a native programme on the PC. But we won't convert it to .net, but it can be execute via dos cmd like:

```
java jar my_send_message.jar -p 12345678 -m This is a testing message.
```

How can the .net programme get used with this little programme? Thanks.

Comment: .NET `Process.Start()` or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could process invoke it, using `Process`, as detailed here:  [How To: Execute command line in C#, get STD OUT results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results)