# Interactively log on another Windows user from c# code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winapi, windows-7

I am trying to achive a situation:

- I am logged as a user on my account.
- I've created a two more accounts which I will try to log on in the
  "background"
- And now I want to execute my code to log on different user in the background,
  so that if i can click ctrl+alt+del and go to the switch user screen
  i can see that another account was logged on the system.

During investigation I've read that this was possbile with some undocumented winapi methods before Microsoft implemented `Fast User Switch(FUS)` which replaced `GINA`.

---

I don't want to Impersonate code as user. I want to start up the whole windows session for a user from code.

I've tried to do sth with `CreateProcessWithLogonW()` but this was unsuccessful.

`Big virtual beer` for anybody who can give me a hand with this! :)

Comment: There are some pointers here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/windowssecurity/thread/5b1d6208-2542-4cf7-858b-2d28c0cd754f

Answer (score 0):

Okay had to do a bit of digging to figure this out my self.

Essentially you would need to run a command in command prompt.

This should load explorer.exe as a second user.

`runas /user:*computer name\*account name explorer.exe`

Follow this to get an idea on running a command line command via c#:

[How To: Execute command line in C#, get STD OUT results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results)

Other sources:

http://www.computerhope.com/runas.htm

http://lifehacker.com/290435/switch-user-accounts-from-the-command-prompt