# Is there any function in c# like 'int system("cmd")' <stdlib.h> in c++ for executing command in cmd prompt?

Tags: c#, .net

I am new to c# programing.I want function like int system("command string") of c++  in c#.

for example: we can execute command  on command prompt by using function `system("winrm") in c++` where "winrm" is command. system() functon is in `stdlib.h` header file.
I want to know whether this kind of function is available in c#. if yes let me know.
Or can i use same system() method in c#? if yes,then tell me how to use?
Thank you !!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seams that you are looking for [`Process Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx). Info from MSDN:

> Provides access to local and remote processes and enables you to start and stop local system processes.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MyProcessSample
{
    class MyProcess
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Process myProcess = new Process();

            try
            {
                myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                // You can start any process, HelloWorld is a do-nothing example.
                myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\HelloWorld.exe";
                myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                myProcess.Start();
                // This code assumes the process you are starting will terminate itself. 
                // Given that is is started without a window so you cannot terminate it 
                // on the desktop, it must terminate itself or you can do it programmatically
                // from this application using the Kill method.
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Added** after comment.

The simplest way to execute command probably is static method [Start(String) of Process class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx) or the other one [Start(String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx) that executes application with arguments.

```
Process.Start("application.exe");
```

or

```
Process.Start("application.exe", "param1 param2");
```

The above example gives you more flexibility. E.g. using [ProcessStartInfo Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) as a parameter to `Start` method that can redirect an input or output for console applications.

Comment: Thank youit, but it is lengthy code for executing single command. i want only 1 line function which accepts command string as i mentioned in my question.

Comment: ok. if i want to execute 1000 command with diffrent parameter, then cmd window will open and close 1000 time. is it possible to hide cmd window while executing commands. i dont want to see what is output after executing command.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you use the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class. You have several options:

```
Process.Start("something.exe", "/arguments"); // Just start a random .exe
Process.Start("cmd", "/C echo hi"); // Start a new command prompt, execute command, and automatically close command prompt at end
Process.Start("cmd", "/K echo hi"); // Start a new command prompt, execute command, but leave it open at the end.
```

Or you can use the full `System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo` class to have a very fine control over how the new process is instantiated. You can wrap it in your own `system()` method if you need to reuse the same settings a lot.

Comment: can i use system() method in c#?

Comment: @sagar - There is no such method, but, as I said, you can make your own.

Answer (score 1):

See the [Process class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx)