# Showing output of a running cmd process

Tags: c#

I have a C# code that uses command prompt to call a python script.  The script currently takes about 25 seconds to run.  When run in command prompt, the python script has several outputs until finally outputting "done".  My C# code runs the script, but never closes the command prompt if I use "WaitForExit".  So my thought is I need some kind of logic to check to see if "done" has been outputted, but the internet has not been very helpful with methodology.

Here's what I have, it currently only outputs the first line, "Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]".  Obviously, no good.

```
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Optimization";
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;


p.Start();


p.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"ipy spot_for_labview.py");

    StreamReader mySR = p.StandardOutput;
    string mystr = mySR.ReadLine();
    Debug.WriteLine(mystr);



p.WaitForExit(25000);  //25000 is a placeholder until better method found.

p.Close();
```

If there's anyway to close the process after it finishes, or to get all the cmd output I'm all ears.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your first suggestion does not seem to output anything.  I don't see how this could work without some kind of event structure or loop, when it first hits the "Debug.WriteLine" line, the output I need will not have happened yet.  If I use p.BeginOutputReadLine(), what other method do I need to use to capture the output?  I can't use p.StandardOutput, apparently that is sync.

Comment: this So link may help !!! - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results

Comment: It appears that process.BeginOutputReadLine() is all that's needed and that makes everything visible?  Doesn't work in my case.

Answer (score 1):

did you try this event ? [Process.OutputDataReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx) Event

or [Process.ErrorDataReceived Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.errordatareceived.aspx)

here is the code from MSDN

```
    Process sortProcess;
    sortProcess = new Process();
    sortProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "Sort.exe";
    sortProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(SortOutputHandler);
```

...
....
...

```
private static void SortOutputHandler(object sendingProcess, 
            DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
        {
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was unable to get that to work.  It would output everything but not until I closed the command prompt manually.

Comment: Essentially.  No -Q though.  I'm not sure what the -Q would do...?

Comment: ProcessEXE.StartInfo.Arguments = Parameters; ? are you using this

Comment: No, is that necessary?  I am just including everything on the StandardInput.WriteLine line.