# how to clear IE cached with selenium IWebDriver?

Tags: c#, selenium

I found the following:

[How to clear browser cache automatically in Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16461472/how-to-clear-browser-cache-automatically-in-selenium-webdriver/22516832#22516832)

However, I don't have the propertity `IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION` for `InternetExplorerDriver` in `C#`.

All I can find to clear it's cache on the web is for java.

What is the equivalent in `C#`? Will also need to do firefox and chrome eventually...

Comment: what version of Selenium are you using?  [`InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9b041165457915895883be4b8aa5566774276acc#diff-41f768943e8ae70d74aa34ec198abe9aR135) was introduced a while ago, back in version 2.35

Comment: thanks for you quick aanswer. 2.53.0 : http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/. But I'm using C#, not java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# has this option in [InternetExplorerOptions.cs](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/c10e8a955883f004452cdde18096d70738397788/dotnet/src/webdriver/IE/InternetExplorerOptions.cs#L340):

```
public bool EnsureCleanSession
{
    get { return this.EnsureCleanSession; }
    set { this.EnsureCleanSession = value; }
}
```

So what you need is something like

```
var options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.EnsureCleanSession = true;
// ...
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
```

If you are using `IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(...)` as you said in the comments, then you can

```
var options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.EnsureCleanSession = true;
DesiredCapabilities cap = (DesiredCapabilities)options.ToCapabilities();
cap.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer());
// continue adding other capabilities
IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(cap)
```

Comment: thank!! however I set my IWebDriver to a new RemoteWebDriver, can I set it?

Comment: do you mean `RemoteWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);`? Yes, that's fine, same thing

Comment: actually I have IWebDriverdriver = new RemoteWebDriver(...)

Comment: Are you using capabilities to specify browser type then?

Comment: yes, DesriedCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.Firefox(); I can set the option in this?

Comment: I added code that lets you work with `RemoteWebDriver`, BUT if you need solution for Firefox, it will be entirely different. As your question stated this is IE only

Comment: did you test it? because I get an error implying capabilities are incorrect...
if not, I'll modify it, I found a way to make it work