# Using Microsoft Web Deploy through Console Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, deployment, web-deployment

I have a asp.net MVC project which I currently deploy through Visual Studio (Build->Publish). I'm aware that I can access this deployment process through command line, but is there any way I can do it through a C# console application?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a reason to use a C# application, I would write a batch file that does the work and invoke it with the C# application.

See this post: [How To: Execute command line in C#, get STD OUT results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results)