# How to execute DOS command and retrieve result

Tags: c#

My C# application requirement is to issue dir command from command line (with J:\MyFolder> as current directory) and receive output from that command in my C# application.

I tried MSDN where issuing command line examples are there like "/c dir" but I would like to retrieve result also.

Can somebody help me with that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results

Comment: Don't do that.  Use `DirectoryInfo`.

Comment: I do not want to use DirectoryInfo as I am going to issue host of other commands. So it may not be useful

Comment: @user2680162 ok, so issue the `DirectoryInfo` for the "dir" and use `Process` for the rest of your commands.

Comment: @user2680162 Please note that capturing the output stream "the simple" way, does not support large amount of data, and can result in a **deadlock**, if you need a sample code for capturing large amounts of data from the command result, reply to this comment...

Answer (score 1):

http://www.dotnetperls.com/process-start 
and http://www.dotnetperls.com/redirectstandardoutput

Y
Ou can use the ProcessStartInfo class to call other exes and .bats etc and redirect the outout and errors back into your c# program. However this is nasty and could be better achieved in direct code probably depending on what logic you are calling in addition to yoir example. Thinhs such as powershell and wmi and basical file and directory handling

Comment: I appreciate your response. However both examples use .exe file execution, not direct commandline execution. Please let me know if you have any such example.

Comment: In the .start () you could do .start ("cmd.exe /C dir") where dir is a command that you could run in a command window. Google what flags cmd.exe has. Depending how complex yours is may determine if this should be done in code which I strongly advise. Once you get the response back you will have to format it with string manipulation.  Yuck.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that.

Use [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx).

Comment: CW since it was previously commented by  SLask

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to start a process using "command.com" as the executable and pass the command line as a parameter as well as redirect the `stdout` back into your program.

I just reviewed these two links: http://www.dotnetperls.com/process-start and
http://www.dotnetperls.com/redirectstandardoutput These are reasonable descriptions of what you need to do.

It really isn't that difficult, mostly just time consuming getting all the details correct!

To test this out prior to programming invoke `command.com` and ensure you can use it to issue commands.  I found my copy of `command.com` at `C:\WINDOWS\system32`.

Hope this helps, please ask if more questions.