# Sending console commands / using windows variables

Tags: vb.net

A two-part question but they tie in together. - I'm experimenting with VB.net console applications and I'm wandering how I send command line commands to the console window. Take the below Sub.

```
Sub initialLoad()
        Console.WriteLine("Started @ " + %date% %time%)
        Console.WriteLine("Test")
    End Sub
```

I'm trying to add the equivalent of `echo.` which would add a line break, I tried using the string `Console.WriteLine("Test", vbCrLf)` but the vbCrLF made no difference and did not add a line break after the text.

The %date% and %time% variables when used on a Batch script for example will give the current date and time and is recognised and defined automatically within the CMD window. Am I able to send these CMD commands to the console or must I use VB.net equivalents to achieve this.

I found that instead of `pause>nul` I had to use `Console.ReadLine()` to make the console window pause.

Am I incorrect in assuming I can use CMD commands? I know in C++ I can send all the commands but is there something similar in VB.net? Thanks.

Comment: How about a blank i.e. no parameter `Console.WriteLine()` to enter a line break?

Comment: You have quite a few (basic) lacks. You don't even know how to use WriteLine (the comma has its meaning and you are using it wrongly). You should learn/experiment much more before asking here in order to get quick/proper help. You should do things step by step: understand firstly how to declare/use variables; then how to use the given method; etc. Also If you come from scripts, bear in mind that VB.NET supports many things (pure .NET, old VB and even kind of scripting). For example: vbCrLf works, but also what SilverLightFox recommends you (which is the .NET version, more recommendable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For environment variables use [Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable.aspx)

For new line use [Environment.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx)

For commands see here: [How To: Execute command line in C#, get STD OUT results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results) - this is in C# but you can use the same objects in VB.NET.