# Speech Recognition Fails Because of Background Noise

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I was trying to learn and work with a Speech Recognition application,
Searched and searched for too long, Found many useful information and guides..

Finally i found and used this project : [HERE](http://ellismis.com/2012/03/17/converting-or-transcribing-audio-to-text-using-c-and-net-system-speech/)

It worked perfectly, until i tried with Some Noisy background samples..

I tried to add a custom Grammar along with Dictation , tried using Custom Grammar only,
but still get same result (or worse)..

```
_speechRecognitionEngine.LoadGrammar(_dictationGrammar);
        _speechRecognitionEngine.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices("a", "b", "c",
            "d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u",
            "v","w","x","y","z","please","type","the","letters","you","hear"))) { Name = "NewGrammar" });
        _speechRecognitionEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
```

Always same result : Please Type The Letters You Hear its staff..

any letters always result : its staff.

So, is there any way to Reduce the background Noise? or edit the WAV sample?

and a newbie question : is it possible to use some audio sample as Choice?
(read it in bytes then compare or whatever).

Audio Sample to test : [Audio Sample](https://www.mediafire.com/?yw6dog41zi2wf8l)

Correct Result for this sample Should be : **Please Type The Letters You Hear H C D V A**.

Comment: a comment with a little explanation would be better than Voting down !! Thanks.

Comment: Can you check the sample you provided? I can't hear it properly, and this is the output of `soxi` run on it:
"soxi FAIL formats: can't open input file `HCDVA.wav': WAVE: RIFF header not found"

Comment: I Used Spectro and got These Values : Sample Rate: 22KHz
Channels: 1
Bits Per Sample: 16
Size: 0.27MB
Average Bitrate: 353kbps ....

Comment: I'm sorry i really don't have any experience in working with Audio files.

Comment: PROGRESS : Using Audacity, 1- select the part that's silent except for the noise, Then choose Effect > Noise Removal and click "Get Profile". 2-Apply Noise Removal Twice. Then Exported the new audio file to test with Speech Recognition Project. Result : Please type letters you hear a CDV 8 (a CDV 8 = H CDV A) almost 80% Success.. any idea how to do this Noise Removal in C# code?!!

Comment: Any Help?! Anyway to remove Background Noise Programmatically ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm exploring a similar problem. You *could* filter the file in question through another application that had a noise removal feature and a scripting or command line mode (such as [Audacity's](http://manual.audacityteam.org/o/man/scripting.html) or [Sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/)). Those could be called from a C# program using the [Process class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results).

Alternately, there is a commercially licensed .NET library for this purpose https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/53d1f3fc-44d2-4a53-8211-99ca4b70536d.